# Nonlinearity of ${\mathbb E}[\epsilon_i|{\mathbf X}]$ and also ${\mathbb E}[\epsilon_i^2|{\mathbf X}]$ under linear regression

Tags: regression, conditional-expectation, conditional-variance

With two of the crucial assumptions of the Classical Linear Regression Model (CLRM) being the zero conditional mean of the error term (${\epsilon_i}$)  and the constant conditional variance of ${\epsilon_i}$, **could someone kindly shed light on how these two functions are inherently nonlinear in** ,  if we were not to assume their values fixed? To make myself clearer, I quote from one of the standard graduate econometrics texts in what follows (see, especially, the emphasized part under quotes).

On page 7 of his book "Econometrics" published by the Princeton University Press in 2000, Fumio Hayashi writes the following:

> Assumption 1.2 (strict exogeneity):
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> \tag{1.1.7}{\mathbb E}[\epsilon_i|{\mathbf X}]=0, (i=1, 2,..., n).
> \end{align*}$$
>
> Here, the expectation (mean) is conditional on the regressors for all observations. This point may be made more apparent by writing the assumption without using the data matrix as
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> {\mathbb E}[\epsilon_i|\mathbf {x_1},...,\mathbf {x_n}]=0, (i=1, 2,...,n).
> \end{align*}$$
>
> To state the assumption differently, take, for any given observation i, the joint distribution of nK+1 random variables, ${{\mathit f}({\epsilon_i}, {\mathbf {x_1}},..., {\mathbf {x_n})}}$ and consider the conditional distribution, ${{\mathit f}({\epsilon_i} {\mid} {\mathbf {x_1}},..., {\mathbf {x_n})}}$. **"The conditional mean** ${{\Bbb E}[{\epsilon_i} {\mid} {\mathbf {x_1}},..., {\mathbf {x_n}]}}$ = 0, (${\mathit i}$ = 1, 2,..., ${\mathit n}$) **is in general a nonlinear function of $(\mathbf {x_1}$,..., $\mathbf {x_n})$".** The strict exogeneity assumption says that this function is zero.

**Q.)** *I am perplexed as to how the mean of $\epsilon_i$ when conditioned on* $(\mathbf {x_1},..., \mathbf {x_n})$ *is nonlinear, if it were  assumed to be zero, especially when the least squares regression function* ${\mathbb E}[\mathbf y_i|\mathbf {x_1},...,\mathbf {x_n}]$ *itself is linear*. Could the same be applicable to the conditional second moment of $\epsilon_i$: ${{\Bbb E}[{\epsilon_i^2} {\mid} {\mathbf {x_1}},..., {\mathbf {x_n}]}}$ as well?  Hayashi mentions that it is so on page 11, but does not elaborate:

> The homoskedasticity assumption (1.1.12)* says that **"the conditional second moment, which is in general a nonlinear function of , is a constant".**

Best Wishes,

ekss.

*Note: The assumption (1.1.12) is as follows:

(homoskedasticity) ${\mathbb E}[\epsilon_i^2|\mathbf {X}] = {\sigma^2} > 0$ (${\mathit i}$ = 1, 2,..., ${\mathit n}$)

Comment: I think this setup is quite unique to econometrics. They like to assume that $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_i|X_i) = f(X_i)$, where $f(X_i)$ can be any function, hence non-linear. Same with $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_i^2|X_i)$. This is the general setup *without* strict exogeneity.

Comment: "In general" does not mean "inherent."

Comment: What you say makes sense, Tim Mak, and @whuber. Dunno why it didn't strike me all this while. May be I'm rusty with my english. Thank you both...